# How to hide database connection information when pushing to Github, but be able to restore them conveniently?

Tags: javascript, express

I am using mongoose to connect to my database. I hardcoded the database information into my code. However, when I publish my code to GitHub, I have to get rid of that database information in my code. How can I restore them when I need them?

Comment: Use a file to store environment variables.

Comment: You should use `.env` file in this case. When you push your code to Github will push `.env.example` file.

Answer (score 0):

I store my database connection details in an external file like `config.json`. I then make a copy of the file `config.json.example` and replace the secure information so others can see and replace it with their own. **Last important step**, add the original `config.json` to your `.gitignore`.

```
{
    "database": "REPLACE_WITH_DB_NAME",
    "password": "REPLACE_WITH_USER",
    "password": "REPLACE_WITH_PASS"
}
```